# css true 100vh for mobile design

Tags: html, css, mobile

Is there a trick to get the actual browser's screen height without worrying with scrollbar & menubar?

I cannot using `-webkit-fill-available` / `-moz-available` because the element is deeply inside another elements. For example i want the hero section is exactly the same as screen size.

I hope you give me the css solution, or js solution if there is no css solution.

Comment: What do you mean by without worrying about scrollbar and menubar? Like the height with them there and height without them there and you expect them to be different?

Comment: `window.innerHeight` changes as the bars appear/disappear

Comment: maybe you can work it out using calc eg height: calc(100vh - 80px)

Comment: @Tristanisginger that would be a really bad advice. besides it does not prevent the scrollbar to take up some of the space. Besides 80px is very exessive. 100vh is always the exact browser screen height. If you have troubles with a scrollbar, give it a width/height of 0 or fix the overflow issue.